# How set scroll state of hidden element

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

So basically I have a `div` element which has vertical scroll. I can change its state from JS using scrollTop property of `div` element and it works fine, but however if I scroll to the very bottom, then hide that element (display: hidden), its scrollTop returns 0 as if it is on top, but when I show it the scroll is at the bottom and scrollTop shows non-0 value. The issue here is that I can't reset scroll position to top while div element is hidden, it restores scroll position when showing. Is there any way to modify/reset actual scroll position which is restored after unhiding element, or is it stored somewhere in browser which is not accessible from JS?

Comment: Can't you simply save the scroll position in a variable before hiding, and set it after showing..?

Comment: You could hide it i.e. by `position: absolute; z-index: -1`; or you can set `visibility` or `opacity` property to avoid the scrollTop reset.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to just save the scroll-position you want to restore into a variable and pass it to `scrollTo` after you make the `div` visible again?

Comment: It sometimes fails as there needs to be some delay between showing and scrolling, if I set 100ms delay user can still see how scroll goes to top from bottom.

Comment: have you experienced this on several browsers? Sounds like the browser sets the scrollState back to the top after redrawing your `div`.